# Xcode Unit Tests - Can't add new test, because it isn't run

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, methods

I'm learning Unit testing in Xcode.
The Xcode generated the template for me, but when I added a new test method it doesn't run.
Why? I allready out of my head. I dont know why and I cant find any solution.

```
    #import <XCTest/XCTest.h>

@interface TesttestTests : XCTestCase

@end

@implementation TesttestTests

 -(void)setUp
{
    [super setUp];
    // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
}

 -(void)tearDown
{
    // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
    [super tearDown];
}

 -(void)testExample
{
    XCTFail(@"No implementation for \"%s\"", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}

 -(void)newtest{
    XCTAssert(false, @"This'll be false");
}
```

So I added the last method, but my test class doesn't recognize it. WHY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for Xcode to recognize that it is a test, you need to start the test method's name with "test". Try this:

```
- (void)testNew {
    XCTAssert(false, @"This'll be false");
}
```

Comment: Huge thanks. Why Apple didn't wrote this in their documentation? :D